# 404 error on route defined in config/routes.js

Tags: angular, sails.js, sails-mongo

I'm refactoring my Angular4+sails app so that both the views and the backend are available on localhost:1337. I've specified the routes in `config/routes.js`

```
module.exports.routes = {

     '/': {
       view: 'homepage'
     },
     '/register':{
       view: 'homepage'
     },

     'POST /user': 'UserController.create',
     'POST /user/login': 'UserController.login',
     /*further code*/

};
```

and I have the `UserController` file with `login` method declared as follows:

```
import { Model } from 'Sails';

declare var sails: any;

module.exports = {

    login: function (req, res) {
        console.log("In controller");
        /*further code*/
    },
/*further code*/

};
```

all code is available here: https://github.com/adzina/web-app-1337

I access the homepage view at `localhost:1337`.Login button declared in `assets/app/components/LoginComponent/` performs a POST request to `localhost:1337/user/login` and the response I get is: `Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:1337/user/login`. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you maybe have a policy blocking the methods of your user controller?

Comment: @arbuthnott in my config/policies.js I don't have any policy that affects the login method. All policies affecting the UserController are described as follows:   UserController: {
    create: 'sessionAuth',
    getAll: 'sessionAuth',
    findByID: 'sessionAuth',
  },

Comment: Have you tried hitting http://localhost:1337/user/login directly from the broswer.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the API via `Postman` or any rest client? Are you able to do that?

Comment: @khushalbokadey turns out I had to add require('ts-node/register') to my app.js file. Since my server was written in typescript it was not being compiled to javascript.